# Rails Model Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Going a little crazy here. I am doing a very simple lookup of a user by its email and then if I have a user checking its role. quick example.

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
if user
  if user.role == 'admin'
    abort("Yay were an admin")
  end
end
```

The user has a role like in the example but the if statement is not returning true.

If I inspect the user ie,

```
if user
  raise user.to_yaml
end
```

I get valid attributes ie.

```
--- !ruby/object:User
attributes:
  id: 1
  email: user@test.com
  created_at: 2011-12-01 08:37:45.000000000Z
  updated_at: 2011-12-01 08:37:45.000000000Z
  role: admin
```

Why would the if statement not return true? I know the user has a roel as if I do if user.role it returns true.

Doing the same in rails console gives me the user role.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > u = User.find_by_email('user@test.com')
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'user@test.com' LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, email: "user@test.com", created_at: "2011-12-01 08:37:45", updated_at: "2011-12-01 08:37:45", role: "admin"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 >
```

But then trying a if statement fails as well

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :008 > if u.role == 'admin'
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :009?>   puts 'Yay'
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :010?>   end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :011 >
```

Any ideas ??

Comment: What does the user instance look like in the console? Is it possible your role return a data type that isn't a string (but would be cast as a String in Yaml, e.g. a symbol) ?

Comment: Hi David,  In console it finds user and role but if statement fails as well.  Ive edited to question.

Comment: could you try this statement to see if the attribute is really returning a string? `user.role.class.name`

Comment: Adding abort(user.role.class.name) gives me  Symbol

Comment: ok now if I do "if user['role']" the statement returns true. I would have thought it would have been user.role or have I got something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments, the `user`'s role attribute returns a symbol. Therefore, your test should be

```
if user.role == :admin
  abort("Yay were an admin")
end
```

Comment: I now worked out why. In the User model I am using a enum plugin which converts the user role to a symbol.  Thank you but I could kick myself

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the column name `role` is reserved, depending on what database you are using, which can cause all kinds of strange conflicts.

I had the same problem with my first Rails project using a column called `error` in sqlite3 - try renaming the `role` column to `project_role` or similar and see if that helps.

There was a great resource for checking reserved names at yup.com which has since gone down, [here](http://www.yup.com.sharedcopy.com/articles/2007/01/31/072824b59123b20543842385aee20449.html) is the only mirror I can find.